# Qt - Android - Including External Files into "files" directory

Tags: android, qt, file, apk, qmake

How to include an external file into "apk" placed at "files" not "assets" using qmake script?

Example:
There is **"`languages.txt`"** in the main directory where *.pro* file exists. What should I add to pro file to put **"`languages.txt`"** into

"`/data/data/com.sample/files`".

I tried `"ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR = $$PWD/android"` which puts anything in `"$$PWD/android/assets"` in apk but with `"QFile::ReadOnly"` access but I need `"QFile::ReadWrite"` access.

there is an work around like `'QFile::copy("assets:/languages.txt", "./languages.txt")'`
which copy's the file where we have write access but I do not like to use that since it looks like doing job twice (first run overhead and double memory usage)